# Proof on Cross - Product of Open Subsets

Tags: general-topology

We're asked to prove the following result:

Let $A$ and $B$ be open subsets of $\mathbf{R}$.  Define $A \times B$ = $\{(x, y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 ~|~ x \in A$ and $y \in B\}$. Then $A \times B$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Here's my sketch at a proof.

We want to show that $\exists \epsilon$ such that $D_{(a,b),\epsilon} \subset A \times B$.  To do that, we need to show that $\forall x, y \in D_{(a, b),\epsilon}, x\in A$ and $y\in B$.  Also, for $(x, y)$ to be in $D_{(a, b),\epsilon}$ means $\sqrt{(a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2} < \epsilon.$  Those are some of my observations.

Let $(a, b) \in A \times B.$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are open subsets of $\mathbf{R}$, $\exists \epsilon_1$,$\epsilon_2$ such that $D_(a,\epsilon_1) \subset A$ and $D_{b,\epsilon_2} \subset B$.  Let $\epsilon =$ max$\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$. Then $\forall x \in D_{a, \epsilon}, \vert x - a \vert < \epsilon$, and $\forall y \in D_{b, \epsilon}, \vert y - a \vert < \epsilon$. We also note that $|~x-a~|$ = $\sqrt{(x - a)^2}$ and $|~y-b~|$ = $\sqrt{(y - b)^2}$.

That's as far as I've can go.  I can't find a way to connect my goal with my givens.  Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: You mean Cartesian product, of course. Cross product isn't applicable here.

Comment: EXACTLY,user14894!

Comment: Yes, of course.  That was pretty dumb

Answer (score 2):

First, take $\varepsilon=\min\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\}$ instead of the maximum, since only then you have $D_{a,\varepsilon}\subset A$ and $D_{b,\varepsilon}\subset B$. Now pick $(x,y)\in D_{(a,b),\varepsilon}$, i.e. $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\varepsilon$. Then $|x-a|=\sqrt{(x-a)^2}\leq\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\varepsilon$ and similarly $|y-b|<\varepsilon$. In particular, $x\in D_{a,\varepsilon}$ and $y\in D_{b,\varepsilon}$, thus $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ and therefore $D_{(a,b),\varepsilon}\subset A\times B$.

Comment: Much appreciated!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First,a correction-choose $\epsilon =$ min$\{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2\}$ since we need the open balls with respect to $D_(x,\epsilon_y) \subset A$ where x = a,b and y = 1,2.We pick x and y in the open ball centered at (a,b) in AxB such that  $(x,y)\in D_{(a,b),\varepsilon}$, i.e. $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\varepsilon$. This also implies that 
 $|x-a|=\sqrt{(x-a)^2}<\varepsilon/2$ and $|y-b|=\sqrt{(y-b)^2}<\varepsilon/2$ in A and B,respectively.

Then use the triangle inequality as follows:

**$||x-y||$** = $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$ $\leq |x-a|+|y-b|$ = $\varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2$ = $\varepsilon$

So $D_((a,b)\epsilon) \subset AXB$  and we're done. Q.E.D.